# Texture names and language file for custom texture pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been making a texture pack and I want to change the texture of the cake item, but I don't know what texture is called. Also, I want to make a language pack but I can't get the lang file. What is the texture for the cake item named and how can I get the language file?

Answer (score 0):

The texture of the cake item is named `cake.png`. [image: cake.png]  It is located in folder `assets\minecraft\textures\items`.

The textures of the cake block are named `cake_bottom.png` [image: cake_bottom], `cake_inner.png` [image: cake_inner], `cake_side.png` [image: cake_side], and `cake_top.png` [image: cake_top].  They are located in folder `assets\minecraft\textures\blocks`.

The language file is named `en_us.lang`.  It is located in folder `assets\minecraft\lang`.

I opened `1.12.2.jar` with 7-Zip and pulled those files out.  I then put them into a texture pack which contains only those files.  It can be [downloaded here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/emee7v96g75m8jg/Example.zip).  It is named Example.zip and is 36.57KB.  If you would rather do this yourself or play a different version, navigate to the Minecraft versions folder and open the jar file, for which ever version you are playing, with an archive editor(WinZip, WinRAR, 7-Zip, etc).